# Custom focus indicator for all browsers

Tags: html, css, focus

Every browser has its own focus indicator like:
*Firefox has a dotted line when an element is focused through keyboard tab key.*
*Chrome has a blue border*

Is there any way to set a custom focus indicator for all browsers?

I have tried the following

```
:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #0000ff; }
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

:focus is a pseudo element and as such it needs to be attached to something else like a link. See my example and click on the link box, it turns red, styled by a:focus attribute. Should work in any browser:

```css
a {
background: #efefef;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus
{
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#">Sample link</a>
```